# show display value instead of id from a LOV in display only table in oracle apex 20

Tags: oracle-apex, lov, oracle-apex-19.2

Am using a LOV in a form like below,

```
Display | Value
------- | -------
A       |  1
------- | -------
B       |  2
------- | -------
C       |  3
------- | -------
```

As you know in a select list display value is the showing value but actual save value is value. The data saved in the data table from this table has the value. But when I display all the data in a table I want to show the display value instead of the saved value. Select list values are from a LOV. Can I use the same LOV to show display value inside the table.? and how.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "Type" of the column. If it is "Plain Text", it will display whatever is in the table (the id if it is a foreign key column). If it is "Plain Text (based on List of Values)" then you can indicate which list of values to use and apex will get the lookup value for you.
Alternatively you can join to each of the lookup tables in the query yourself. That has the advantage that you have more control over the query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Koen. The other lesser known approach is to leverage some of the inbuilt APEX functions in Apex and this can be useful,

```
wwv_flow_item.text_from_lov(p_value, p_lov)
```

p_value is the value and p_lov is the name of the List of Values.